# Best practice for tag management for docker images that's pushed from Azure Devops to AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-devops, amazon-ecr

I have created a CI on Azure DevOps and I am pushing the image that has been created to AWS-ECR.

I have encountered some issues with maintaining the tags that have been given to the images.
I would like to follow this pattern `MAIN_VERSION:SUB_VERSION:(latest_tag for X:Y+1)+1`

Let's say my latest image is: `1.1.1`, I want to have the tag `1.1.2` on the next time I am triggering the build.

This is my current setting for the CI:

```
# Docker
# Build a Docker image
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  - group: dev

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - script: |
        aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-central-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID).dkr.ecr.$(AWS_REGION).amazonaws.com
      displayName: 'Login to AWS'
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build docker image
      inputs:
        repository: $(REPOSITORY_URI)
        command: buildAndPush
        tags: |
          $(MAIN_VERSION).$(SUB_VERSION).$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

How can I do that?

In addition to that, how can I set in the script that the image that just been created is the `latest`?

Comment: Basically you have to use a GItVersion task in azure devops. Here is a useful tutorial for you https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/automatically-version-docker-container/ . Also please refer to the documentation [link](https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/build-servers/azure-devops)  and [link](https://github.com/GitTools/actions/blob/main/docs/examples/azure/gitversion/setup/usage-examples.md)

Comment: Additionally: `tags` takes multiple entries. So you could add `latest` to the list of tags. However, I'd generally avoid tagging with `latest`, it just encourages people to *run* `latest` instead of relying on a known-good version.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Klevi for his comment, which helped me.

I needed to install [GitTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gittools) extension at Azure DevOps
[image]

I have created new file at `/` with the name `GitVersion.yml` with the content:
`mode: Mainline`

After that I have added those line onto my `steps` section at the top.

```
 - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0
    - task: gitversion/setup@0
      displayName: Install GitVersion
      inputs:
        versionSpec: "5.10.x"
    
    - task: gitversion/execute@0
      displayName: Determine Version
      inputs:
        useConfigFile: true
        configFilePath: ./GitVersion.yml
```

Build and enjoy!